# How to login in RingCentral softphone in ipad ios in developer sandbox mode

Tags: ringcentral

I have installed RingCentral Softphone in my ipad.

How to login in softphone in ipad ios in developer sandbox mode. I tried to check different options, but unable to find one

In Mac Os, I can switch to Sandbox via `Cmd+F2` keys... but in iPad not finding solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think in iOS, it may not be possible for sandbox mode as it doesn't support.. RingCentral Phone mobile app does not support sandbox mode.

I can get this reference: https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/1289/is-it-possible-to-use-sandbox-account-with-ios-app.html